# Getting Order details from PayPal API JavaScript to save to a database

Tags: javascript, web, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm trying to save my customer details into a database. How can I get other customer details like shipping address?

I'm using the following to get the name and order id of the transaction

```
return actionsenter code here.order.capture().then(function(details) {
>                     var order_id = details.id;
>                     var name = details.payer.name.given_name +" "+details.payer.name.surname; }
```

But when I try to get the address based on the json pattern to get other details its returning `undefined`.

```
var name = details.purchase_units.shipping.address.address_line_1;
```

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#definitions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use JavaScript to do a capture and then relay details to save it to a database.

Instead, use a server-side integration.  Here's the UI code: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

On the server end you will need two corresponding routes, one to 'Set Up Transaction' and one to 'Capture Transaction', documented here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/

This way, you won't be sending captured details to a server, because the capture will be occurring *from* a server--and there will be an immediate API response on the server with all the details.

---

Your particular question about things being undefined just means you need to do better troubleshooting of a `console.log(details)` or equivalent to find out the precise location of what you're looking for.  It's probably something trivial like needing `purchase_units[0]`